# Connection not being established between HttpURLConnection and HttpServer

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, httpserver, httpconnection

Here's an oversimplified server-client connection in Java that doesn't seem to work. I've made a server that serves properly to a browser. I've also made a http connection that receives data fine from an internet site. However, getting the two to talk to each other seems to be difficult.

I have three classes. Common contains strings and data for the Server and Client classes to use.

Common.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Common {

    public static class Data implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public String value = null;

        public Data(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static final String PROTOCOL = "http";

    public static final String HOST = "localhost";

    public static final Integer PORT = 39640;

    public static final String PAGE = "/test";

    public static final String POST = "POST";
}
```

Server.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class Server {

    public static class Handler implements HttpHandler {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
            exchange.getResponseHeaders().add("accept", "*/*");
            try {
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(exchange.getRequestBody());
                Common.Data data = (Common.Data) in.readObject();
                System.out.println(data.value);
                exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
                exchange.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                exchange.sendResponseHeaders(404, 0);
                exchange.close();
            }           
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InetSocketAddress socketAddress = null;
        HttpServer server = null;
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(Common.HOST);
            socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, Common.PORT);
            server  = HttpServer.create(socketAddress, 10);

            //Add contexts
            server.createContext(Common.PAGE, new Handler());

            server.start();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Common.PROTOCOL, Common.HOST, Common.PORT, Common.PAGE);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod(Common.POST);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();

            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(new Common.Data("Hello world"));

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I used ss -nt to determine that a connection is in some way occurring, even though no data is being transferred.

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                      Local Address:Port                        Peer Address:Port 
ESTAB      0      0                               10.0.2.15:46759                      108.168.151.6:80    
ESTAB      0      0                               10.0.2.15:59918                    198.252.206.149:443   
ESTAB      0      0                               127.0.0.1:39030                          127.0.0.1:52906 
ESTAB      0      0                        ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39640                   ::ffff:127.0.0.1:35764
ESTAB      0      0                        ::ffff:127.0.0.1:35764                   ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39640
ESTAB      0      0                        ::ffff:127.0.0.1:52906                   ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39030
```

Comment: I should mention that this example code didn't have the exchange.close() in the handler. I added that, but my project code has the close() method called, so that wasn't part of my original issue.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve changed the following points and it works, in a laptop with Windows Vista and JDK 1.6.0_10 :

Commons:

```
public static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";
//I´ve changed it to the localhost ip (windows)
```

Server, in the handle method, writing some chars to output and closing the exchange:

```
 public void handle(final HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        exchange.getResponseHeaders().add("accept", "*/*");
        try {
            final ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(exchange.getRequestBody());
            final Common.Data data = (Common.Data) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(data.value);
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
            exchange.getResponseBody().write("Hello!".getBytes());

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(404, 0);
        } finally {
            exchange.close();
        }
```

In Client class, I read the InputStream from response and print it:

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    try {
        final URL url = new URL(Common.PROTOCOL, Common.HOST, Common.PORT, Common.PAGE);
        final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod(Common.POST);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        final ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(new Common.Data("Hello world"));
        out.close();
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the line 
URL url = new URL(Common.PROTOCOL, Common.HOST, Common.PORT, Common.PAGE); to Url url = new URL("http://localhost:39640"); works for some reason. But I want the individual values to be passed in as parameters in the end result, so...

Comment: No, changing it back still works. The line that made it work is IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream()); I guess this is because the act of requesting from the input stream forces the server to process the request?

Comment: @AaronF In the client if you close the InputStream: connection.getInputStream().close(); it also works.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens unless you get the input stream, the error stream, or the response code.

This is because the output is buffered until you do so, so that the Content-length header can be set accurately.

You can bypass that by using chunked or fixed-length transfer mode.